# Accessing lib folder of Tomcat in azure app services

Tags: spring-boot, azure-web-app-service, keycloak

Is it possible to access the lib folder of Tomcat, CATALINE_HOME/lib, in azure app services.
I am looking for integrating keycloak into my springboot application, packaged as WAR, using the Tomcat adapters. This requires a couple of jar files to be included in the CATALINE_HOME/lib of tomcat.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CATALINA_HOME directory isn’t on the /home drive, so if you put them there the .jar’s wouldn’t be shared across your instances.  you can upload the .jar’s to /home/tomcat/lib, which is mentioned in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-java?pivots=platform-linux#finalize-configuration). /home/tomcat/lib is added to Tomcat’s class loader, so the .jar will be added just like when you put under CATALINA_HOME/lib.