# How to hide tomcat server information in azure app service?

Tags: tomcat, azure-web-app-service

How do I hide server information of tomcat in azure app service? I found [this tutorial](https://narayanatutorial.com/owasp/disable-apache-tomcat-server-version) and used the 3rd approach, it's working on my local tomcat setup.

I tried to do the same on my azure app by creating /home/tomcat/lib folder in the ftp directory as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65652860/accessing-lib-folder-of-tomcat-in-azure-app-services) to act as its lib folder, and did the same in the 3rd approach but the server name isn't being changed.

EDIT: I'm using linux environment in app service.

Comment: What Tomcat version are you using? On a recent Tomcat 9.0, if I add an empty `ServerInfo.properties` the server info becomes `Apache Tomcat/9.0.x-dev` (this is the default if the `server.info` property is not present).

Comment: Hi @PiotrP.Karwasz, I'm using tomcat 9 in azure app service, where do I put the ServerInfo.properties? I'm using linux environment in the app service by the way.

Comment: hi @PiotrP.Karwasz , I managed to make it work by following this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091137/how-to-extend-errorreportvalve-in-tomcat-on-azure-paas) and using the web.config from [here](https://prashanthmadi.github.io/2018/01/08/using-custom-tomcat-configuration-in-azure-app-services-new.html), but I used the linux pathing for the server.xml instead.

instead of 

D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.5.20\..

I used

/usr/local/tomcat... etc.

Comment: changing `ServerInfo.properties` is the best way to mask Tomcat's version (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2266475/11748454)). As I don't use Azure, I can't tell you how to modify Azure's Tomcat installation. My remark merely stated, that using an empty file is not enough, because there are compiled in defaults. Modify the [original file](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/java/org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties) instead.

Comment: Hello again @PiotrP.Karwasz, please disregard my answer above, I reviewed what I did and put it in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work by copying the server.xml from /usr/local/tomcat/conf using SSH in the advanced tools of app service and using this config in it.

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
    showReport="false" 
    showServerInfo="false"/>
```

then I placed the new server.xml in {home}/tomcat/conf folder and restarted the application.